# I try to upload a image and get that image into base64 format in IE9 using javascript.but i faced issue.please any one help me

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

This is my javascript code.

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
  var filerdr = new FileReader();
  filerdr.onload = function(e) {

    $('#imgprvw' + fieldno).attr('src', e.target.result);

    var imgFileSize = input.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (imgFileSize <= 1) {
      var base64image = e.target.result;
      console.log(base64image);
    }
    else {
      var base64image = jic.compress(document.getElementById('imgprvw' + fieldno), 90, ext);
    }

    var imageBase64 = base64image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
  }
}
```

im using javascript for IE9.i used filereader API and polyfills also. but i didnt get the solution

Comment: Hi @Priyanga.S, welcome to StackOverflow! To increase the quality of your question (and potential answers), please identify and describe the specific issue that you are running into (what is happening vs. what are you expecting to happen). Your question's title and body should be updated to reflect this issue.

Comment: hi am new to stackoverflow. i want to upload a image in IE9 and need to send image in base64 format for Java developers. but thats not works in IE9. can you help me?

Comment: It looks like your real issue is that FileReader is not compatible with IE9. This requires a work around for browser compatibility. Take a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15665917/1708147. 

Short answer: I wouldn't try to ajax a file upload if you need to support IE9 or below. Redesign the code to allow a file upload from a form input.

Comment: IE9 holds 0.51% of the browser marketshare World wild. anything less then 1% is not worth spending time on